# What is the second parameter in method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code block as below in one of my javascript file.

```
 atob('string', function(match, p1){

//...

}
```

I understand that atob stands for ASCII to Binary.

But what is the second parameter?

**Edit**: added method signature

Comment: The second param is a function definition - is that what you are asking about, though?

Comment: No idea. AFAIK `atob` only takes one parameter. What does the function look like?

Comment: Do you have a custom `atob` function? Does removing the second parameter have any effect on the result?

Comment: Try deleting now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-atob) (and [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)) show `atob` as taking only one argument.

So, unless the `atob` function has been overridden, it means nothing and will be ignored.

Comment: May be you are right. I can't even delete the questionnow :)

Answer (score -1):

Only one parameter according ot [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)